# Jquery.css() doesn't work before JQuery.effect()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a code in jQuery, where I am using jquery to dynamically change css of a div.

The code is working when I write it without a succeeding .effect() call.

Working Code

```
 $('.col1').on('mouseenter',function(){
            $('.col1').css('opacity','1');
        }).on('mousedown', function () {
            $('.col1').css('opacity','.6');
        }).on('mouseup', function () {
            $('.col1').css('opacity','1');
 });
```

Now, When I do the following effect() call, it doesn't work any more.

Not working.

```
$('.col1').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('.col1').css('opacity','1');
    }).on('mousedown', function () {
        $('.col1').css('opacity','.6').effect( "shake", { direction: "up", times: 2, distance: 10}, 500);
    }).on('mouseup', function () {
        $('.col1').css('opacity','1');
    });
```

What is it that is going wrong here ?

This part which is not working is : `$('.col1').css('opacity','.6')`
after shake() is added to the code.

Comment: `effect()` isn't part of jQuery core, are you including plugin like jQueryUI that has that method? What errors are thrown?

Comment: The shake is working perfectly fine. $('.col1').css('opacity','.6') is not working.

Comment: Could try it by chaining `css()` after `effect()`

Comment: Replicate issue online so it can be checked

Comment: chaining css() after effect() doesn't work either.

Comment: [Here's a CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/ogdgjd) It looks to me like the `.effect()` code is just stepping on the style.

Comment: If I add a "complete" callback to the `.effect()` call, and from there invoke the code to reset the opacity to 0.6 after a short timeout, then it goes from gray to black (shaking) and then to gray. Personally I would consider this a bug, but I learned some time ago that I think about the world much differently than do the jQueryUI team.

Comment: Wow, if I change it so that it adds a class before the effect, the element has that class removed when the effect is done!

Comment: this doesn't work, without the call-back! But works with the call-back.